# How to join fetch only selected children entities with parent entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm trying to select only certain entities alongside the parent by ids. Is this possible? Example (boilerplate omitted):

```
class Parent {
   int id;
   List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
   int id;
   ...
}
```

And my JpaRepository:

```
interface ParentRepo extends JpaRepo<Parent,Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Parent p JOIN p.children c WHERE p.id = :parentId and c.id IN(:childIds")
    Parent getParentByIdAndChildIds(int parentId, List<Integer> childIds)
}
```

My expectation is that calling:

```
parentRepo.getParentByIdAndChildIds(1, Arrays.asList(1,2,3))
```

will return the parent object with only 3 child entities attached, but instead, I get ALL of the children (i.e. children with ids from 1-10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That wouldn't make any sense, because the whole entity graph needs to be fetched. Consider a parent `p` having children `c1`, `c2` and `c3` and only ids of `c1` and `c2` are passed to your method. If you fetch a `Parent` entity with `c1` and `c2` only, then what happens, if you do something like this:

```
p = parentRepo.getParentByIdAndChildIds(1, Arrays.asList(1,2));
p.getChildren().add(c3);
parentRepo.save(p); // what happens?
```

Creating a new child does not make sense, because there already exists one in the database. On the other hand the default behavior of jpa would delete relationship between `p` and `c3` when saved without modifying:

```
p = parentRepo.getParentByIdAndChildIds(1, Arrays.asList(1,2));
parentRepo.save(p); // is the relationship between p and c3 destroyed
```

Consider creating a bidirectional relationship (also from `Child` to `Parent`) and fetching the `Child` entities only (from `ChildRepository`):

```
interface ChildRepository extends JpaRepository<Child, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT c FROM Child c WHERE c.parent.id = :parentId and c.id IN(:childIds)")
    List<Child> getParentByIdAndChildIds(int parentId, List<Integer> childIds)
}
```

That way you only get the `Child` entities you want, but also `Parent` is reachable from any `Child` (`children.get(0).getParent()`).

Comment: Alright, thank you. Makes sense. Need to go from bottom up and not top-> bottom.

Comment: @OgnjenMišić exactly, have a great day!